# Ruby Rails :Is it possible to overload index method in ActionController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, indexing, overloading

I want some thing like below

```
    class CompanyController < ApplicationController
       def index
           #return all of companies 
       end
       def index
           #return companies based filter on company :name, :location, :type (any combination of these)
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that but you can do something like this:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
   def index
      if params[:name] # add ifs etc
        @companies =  Company.where(:name => params[:name])
      else
        @companies = Company.all
      end
   end
end
```

I think thats what you mean (tell me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: I have implemented this already the way you did. Still can u please tell me or refer to link for how to overload index method based upon input parameter whether its :id or :company

Comment: you can't, just use a if statement

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two methods with the same name in Ruby. If you have multiple methods with the same name, the last method defined will be the one that Ruby uses.